# Extraction of filename

Tags: php, extract, filenames

Let's say I have a string like:

> Cant_Hold_Us_-_Fingerstyle_Guitar_0.mp3

How can I get rid of `_0.mp3` dynamically with PHP? The values are not hard-coded for the current example. Maybe if i use `explode`?

Comment: @trincot You know what they meant. You can point out the typo without the sarcasm.

Comment: you need to specify the range of potential file names and what you want to change them to

Comment: @trincot You know what i've meant

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$old = "your file name here";
$new = substr($old, 0, strrpos($old, "_"));
```

The `substr` method will take only the part of the string that you want.

The `strrpos` method finds the last index of the underscore and passes that number into the `substr` method so that it knows how far to cut. This method is ideal because rather than hardcoding a specific value, the script will dynamically change for each file, just as you suggested.

Just a bit of warning: if the file name does not contain an underscore, the method won't know where to cut to and will cause error in execution. A good bit of practice would be checking `if (strrpos($old, "_") !== false)`.

Comment: A little bit of error handling / explanations might help. What happens if there is no "_" in the string ?

Comment: There will always be "_" in the string. This specifies the version of the file

Comment: Then this should work for you without needed to use the if statement :)

Answer (score 2):

I like Confiqure's answer. To complement, you could also use a regular expression if you find that you need more power.

```
$old = "Cant_Hold_Us_-_Fingerstyle_Guitar_0.mp3";
$new = preg_replace('/_\d+\.mp3$/', '', $old);
```

Answer (score 1):

Regex is your friend. Have a look at `preg_match` and / or `preg_replace`.

`$title = preg_replace("/_[0-9]+\.mp3$/i", "", $x);`

Works for blablabla_21.mp3 as well....